# How to use backspace to erase last character in search string?

Tags: isearch

When I am using incremental search, a backspace erases the character from the *matched string* in the buffer, instead of erasing the character from the search string I am typing. I saw that this is not the case with another emacs user... is there something I have messed up that is causing this issue?

I did rebind my backspace and delete keys, just to be consistent across terminals/keyboards:

```
;; Lock DEL and backspace key behavior
(global-set-key (kbd "<delete>") 'delete-char)
(global-set-key (kbd "<backspace>") 'delete-backward-char)
```

Any suggestions?

FYI, I generally correct my search string using 
    M-e <

Comment: Start emacs with `emacs -q`, evaluate that code snippet, and try again. Does it still happen?

Comment: @Malabarba... Yup... So now I'm sure of what was messing my config... Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to change

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<backspace>") 'delete-backward-char)
```

either to

```
(global-set-key (kbd "DEL") 'delete-backward-char)
```

or to nothing at all.  The definition you use prevents Emacs from remapping `backspace` to `DEL`, and the Isearch behavior you want is bound to `DEL`.

Comment: That's going to fail on terminals where Backspace sends ^H and Delete sends ^?. Granted this isn't common anymore.

Comment: @Gilles: This is another issue, solved with `normal-erase-is-backspace-mode`.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks... I'll try. But I couldn't understand... why such a confusion between DEL and bksp keys? Shouldn't the behavior be consistent across modes?

Comment: @Stefan: Okay... It's fixed now! Thanks for the solution! However, using any of the arrow keys in a search string still makes cursor movements on the matched string... any way to sort this out? It could be useful in cases where my correction lies some characters before my current position...

Comment: Removing `(global-set-key (kbd "<backspace>") 'delete-backward-char)` worked. Kept the `DEL` key binding because DEL was behaving funny otherwise.

Comment: If you want to use cursor keys to to more complex editing than just removing the last char, then use `M-e` which will temporarily suspend Isearch and put you in a normal minibuffer where you can use all the usual editing commands, except for `C-s` which will jump you right back to the Isearch.